# Keep cell constant Excel

Tags: excel

My Excel is high. I now have the 2013 edition.
Previously, I used `=A1/$A33` to keep the denominator konstant,
like a normal person would. But now, instead of letters I 
have numbers at the top. So a cell looks like R119C2 indicating 
rows and columns. So now when I want to do a division it looks like:

```
 =R[-30]C/R[-30]C[41]
```

Which previously would have been B88/RN88 or something.
So `R[-30]` means take the cell 30 steps up. After `/` comes
something that means 30 steps up and 41 steps to the left.
Now I want to keep the denominator constant but using $ apparently
does not work. I have tried using () around the denominator,
tried appling it only before C like `R[-30]$C[41]`. Does not work.
Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Your excel is not high!

Go to file and select options.

Select formulas and untick "R1C1 reference style" as shown in screen shot below:
[image]

Or, if you prefer R1C1 style, you can just change the formula to constants by highlighting and clicking F4. So instead of R[-30]C[41], it will change to R50C50, assuming you want row 50 and column 50. Removing the square brackets turns them to constants.